# How to retrieve element from IQueryable in Parallel Loop

Tags: linq, iqueryable, parallel.for

I got the my records here.

```
IQueryable<EmployeeItem> dtEmployee = GetAll();
```

After that loop that `dtEmployee`.

This is my normal loop which is working fine.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dtEmployee.Count(); i++)  
{  
    var drEmployee = dtEmployee.AsEnumerable().ElementAt(i);  
}
```

This is the parallel loop that I want to try.

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(0, dtEmployee.Count(), i => {
    var drEmployee = dtEmployee.AsEnumerable().ElementAt(i);
});
```

I don't have any compile errors but when I run it in my Visual Studio, I got this error:

[image: screen shot]

Comment: I don't see any image using the provided link. What's your motivation to run this in parallel by the way? It won't speed up anything.. And you are calling AsEnumerable() way to many times. Just materialize the IQueryable with an .ToList()

Comment: Can you check whitch variable is null?

Comment: try changing the variable name , 'var drEmployee' to something else

Comment: What does `GetAll()` do? Is it a database query? Why are you using `for` instead of `foreach`?

Comment: Hi @PeterBons, the reason to use the parallel is to speed up my original for loop.  And it did speed up a lot.  Last time, original loop took 2 hours.  After changing to Parallel, it takes around 10 minutes.  Is it because of IQueryable is not thread safe?

Comment: Hi @llouk, for example, there are no items at i index of dtEmployee.  But actually, it has the records.  It only happens inside of hte parallel loop.

Comment: Hi @AmitPore, changing the variable won't work :(  Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Hi @svick, yes, GetAll() is a database query.  I thought that for and foreach would be the same

Answer (score 0):

> This is my normal loop which is working fine.

I wouldn't say fine, it's incredibly inefficient. Since `dtEmployee` represents a *query*, and `AsEnumerable()` means it's no longer a database query, just a lazy sequence, each `ElementAt()` (and also the `Count()`) causes a separate database query, which likely retrieves all the employees.

To fix this, use `foreach`:

```
foreach (var drEmployee in dtEmployee)
{
}
```

> This is the parallel loop that I want to try.

Since `dtEmployee` is not thread-safe, you can't access it from multiple threads at the same time. The fix here is actually pretty much the same as above: use `Parallel.ForEach()`:

```
Parallel.ForEach(dtEmployee, drEmployee => {
});
```

Comment: Hi @svick, sure, I will try that first.